# Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException [Semantical Error] ...: Error: Class 'NULL' is not defined. when using NULL in QueryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

```
$result = $this->er->createQueryBuilder("r")
            ->select("COUNT(r.customer IS NOT NULL) as customers")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I'm trying to run this query using Doctrine Query Builder but it returns this error: `Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException  [Semantical Error] ...: Error: Class 'NULL' is not defined. when using NULL` What am I doing wrong? How can I implement `IS NOT NULL` into my query?

### EDIT

Also, please consider this:

```
$result = $this->er->createQueryBuilder("r")
                ->select(
                         "COUNT(r.customer) as customers_total", 
                         "COUNT(r.customer IS NOT NULL) as customers_set", 
                         "COUNT(r.customer IS NULL) as customers_unset"
                )
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Therefore, adding `->where("r.customer IS NOT NULL")` would't work much here. My first question wasn't defined precisely. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Why are you not using Eloquent along with Laravel?

Comment: I have decided to use Doctrine2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
$result = $er
            ->createQueryBuilder("r")
            ->select("COUNT(r.customer) as customers_total")
            ->addSelect("SUM(CASE WHEN r.customer IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as customers_set")
            ->addSelect("SUM(CASE WHEN r.customer IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as customers_unset")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: This works... Any clue why `SUM` works and `COUNT` gives `[Syntax Error] line 0, col ##: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'`?

Comment: @simPod As far as I know, the only way to do what you're requesting using querybuilder is the one I provided. Count doesn't work using case, sorry

Comment: It's ok, doesn't really matter what is used in my case. I'm glad it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$result = $this->er->createQueryBuilder("r")
            ->select("COUNT(*) as customers")
            ->where("r.customer IS NOT NULL")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

**EDIT :**

If you want a more complex request

```
    $this->er->createQueryBuilder("r")
                    ->select("COUNT(r.customer) as customers_total,
COUNT(case when r.customer IS NOT NULL then 1 end) as customers_set,
COUNT(case when r.customer IS NULL then 1 end) as customers_unset
")
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but what if I want to make it more complex like `->select("COUNT(r.customer) as customers_total", "COUNT(r.customer IS NOT NULL) as customers_unset", "COUNT(r.customer IS NULL) as customers_set")` I'm going to update my Q as it interests me :)

Comment: I have just edited my post. I think it's the answer you were expecting

Comment: Now it gives me `[Syntax Error] line 0, col ##: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'` Have no idea what to do with that error, tried Google already

Comment: If `COUNT` gets replaced by `SUM` it works. No idea why so far. Maybe just because it's not supported by SQL?

Comment: You are right, I tested it on Oracle. If you have Mysql, SUM is the right solution.